# Double Click Event on Shapes

Tags: vba, excel, events, shapes

In my research, I've found that there is no built in functionality for enabling double click events on Shapes on an excel sheet.  Many of the workarounds I saw involved writing classes or other such things to add this functionality, all of which seemed a bit beyond my VBA knowledgebase.  Hence, I wrote the above code (currently just as a test) to attempt to write my own Double click functionality for shapes.

```
Public Clicked As Boolean, LastClickObj As String, LastClickTime As Date


Sub GenerateShapes()
    Dim sheet1 As Worksheet, shape As shape
    Set sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set shape = sheet1.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeDiamond, 50, 50, 5, 5)
        shape.OnAction = "ShapeDoubleClick"
    Set shape = sheet1.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 50, 60, 5, 5)
        shape.OnAction = "ShapeDoubleClick"
    LastClickTime = Now
End Sub


Sub ShapeDoubleClick()

    If Second(Now) - Second(LastClickTime) > 0.5 Then
        Clicked = False
        LastClickObj = ""
        LastClickTime = Now
    Else

        If Not Clicked Then
            Clicked = True
            LastClickObj = Application.Caller
        ElseIf LastClickObj = Application.Caller Then
            MsgBox ("Double Click")
            Clicked = False
            LastClickObj = ""
            LastClickTime = Now - 1
        Else
            LastClickObj = Application.Caller
            Clicked = True
            LastClickTime = Now
        End If
    End If


End Sub
```

However, given the way I've encorporated the timer, the code often will only execute the "Double click" if I click three times in rapid succession.  I think it has something to do with how I am handling the time-out "resetting" of `Clicked`, but there could be other issues with the logic. Any ideas on how to properly implement this functionality *without other extensive additions* (like Classes and such)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spent some more time looking at this and realized with some debugging that the triple click was caused by my clicked boolean.  The solution I have below works perfectly, including shape distinctions, and the click delay can be easily adjusted in the code (I may adjust that to be a variable set elsewhere, but for now hardcode functionality is sufficient).  Posting my solution here for future users who wish to add Double Click actions to their shapes

```
Option Explicit

Public LastClickObj As String, LastClickTime As Date

Sub ShapeDoubleClick()

    If LastClickObj = "" Then
        LastClickObj = Application.Caller
        LastClickTime = CDbl(Timer)
    Else
        If CDbl(Timer) - LastClickTime > 0.25 Then
            LastClickObj = Application.Caller
            LastClickTime = CDbl(Timer)
        Else
            If LastClickObj = Application.Caller Then
                MsgBox ("Double Click")
                LastClickObj = ""
            Else
                LastClickObj = Application.Caller
                LastClickTime = CDbl(Timer)
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Ha! I also figured the clicked was the problem for triple clicking - nice solution you found. It was a good puzzle!

Comment: @DavidG Chose to use a timer because it takes the time since midnight in seconds (thus the only possible trip-up can happen if two clicks cross midnight which is highly unlikely in this usage)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT 3: I used your initial format with no tracker cells for this:
I think it rounds up the time so you'd have to use the syntax I used above to get it to work in milliseconds. Prevents triple clicking from activating 2 double clicks.

```
Sub ShapeDoubleClick()

    Debug.Print Second(Now) - Second(LastClickTime)

    If Second(Now) - Second(LastClickTime) > 0.3 Then
        LastClickTime = Now

    ElseIf LastClickObj = Application.Caller And Clicked = False Then

            Debug.Print "Double Clicked!"
            Clicked = True
            LastClickTime = Now - 1
            LastClickObj = Application.Caller
            Exit Sub

    End If

    Clicked = False
    LastClickObj = Application.Caller
End Sub
```

Comment: Meant to remove that tracker cell (was just there while i was debugging since the msgbox interrupts the macro).  The trouble here is that this won't require the double click to occur on the same object (which is necessary since the final implementation will contain a plethora of generated shapes)

Comment: Easy replacement for the tracker cell is just another public variable representing the last time, so that's an easy fix

Comment: Also, i dont think this will work correctly if Now is only passing in whole second values.  Are you aware of whether or not it includes fractions of seconds?

Comment: See my edit. Only problem now is when it goes over 60 and that anything under 1 second works as double click.